# I am creating RDLC report in Dot net. I am getting default export options(Excel,PDF,Word)

Tags: .net, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

I am creating RDLC report in Dot net. I am getting default export options(Excel,PDF,Word). I want to add new export options like MHTML, TIFF File.. Is it possible to add them from the Dotnet...

Comment: You can specify a format via URL Access : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/export-a-report-using-url-access?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I want the export options for ProcessingMode local report..

Comment: Then this article might be of help:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ecd99f0a-1f29-4340-b28f-c1d0eb5b36b2/how-to-configure-the-export-options-in-report-viewer-control-dynamically-using-cnet?forum=sqlreportingservices